# Handle page refresh/f5 angular js and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am building an application with angular js( new to angular js ) and laravel. All laravel routes except home page route serves only json data needed for that page. Home page loads all the necessary stuff that angular js has to work with. The problem is that if user decides to refresh the page when he/she is on a url other than home page, the page displays only json data, since there is no css,script and html loaded. My question is what is the best and professional way of handling page refresh/f5 with angular? Should i prevent the page refresh at all, if yes how? Hope my question is clear enough...

Comment: You should add all required js and css in index page and load other html/php file from there with the help of angularjs to fix this problem.

Comment: This is exactly how my current site works. suppose i am on my say user list partial view if i hit enter only the json data is displayed. this is my issue. hope i am clear enough

Comment: Which type of url you have with # or without # ?

Comment: Actually your question is not good enough to understand.are you changing url with your angular request ? Like your home page url is www.abc.com/home and your angular changes it to www.abc.com/userlist and when you enter or refresh url, json comes?

Comment: yes angular changes the url and on angular routes i am sending http request which gives me back the json data which i use to fill my partial views...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102071/discussion-between-sonu-r-and-nouphal-m).

Answer (score 0):

According to your post and comment here are 3 proposed solutions/suggestion.

1. Stay on one url and manage the json only,dont  change your url it direct to your laravel route request if refreshed by user.
2. Using angularjs default hashtag(#) method is better, to understand angular and laravel.
3. Send a variable with your angularjs request to route to identify that it comes from angular and check in your route. If from angular return json otherwise you can redirect to home page.

I hope it will help